# Preventing broken images hitting Rails in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-pow

Anyone know of a simple way to prevent broken images hitting Rails in development?

Sometimes I need to load the production database to debug a specific problem, and the broken images add noise to the logs and slows down Rails.

I'm using pow and am proxying https requests through nginx (on Mac OS X Lion).

**[Update]**

After upgrading to rails 3.1.3 and adding `config.serve_static_assets = false` to `development.rb`, the problem still exists.

Here's an example from the logs:

```
Started GET "/system/template_pics/images/000/000/043/original-254f3340aa9285267db373d8f479144e-1327358518/home6.jpeg" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Feb 27 14:42:34 +1100 2012

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/template_pics/images/000/000/043/original-254f3340aa9285267db373d8f479144e-1327358518/home6.jpeg"):
```

Comment: looking at the names these are not assets

Comment: True, they're paperclip uploads.

Comment: maybe set up a rsync to get the images, I dont think you can disable paperclip on development. Mind you, this has NOTHING to do with the asset pipeline.

Comment: Maybe you should setup a rsync script to sync with your production environment. You cannot disable this, and it definately doesnt go trough the asset pipeline

Comment: Good suggestion @BenjaminUdinktenCate; I've done that on other projects but this one has tens of thousands of images stored on S3 so it's not practical to rsync them all.

Answer (score 0):

Set rails to not serve static assets in `config/development.rb`:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Nginx should be setup to serve static assets itself, and any that don't exist won't be server by Rails.

Comment: Thanks, but adding that and restarting didn't seem to have any effect - the log file still shows routing errors from broken images. Btw it's a rails 3.0.10 app.

Answer (score 0):

I have a script that deals with updating the development database with a MySQL dump from production, and in it I make sure to zero out the Paperclip fields so that the regular `missing.png` is loaded on dev and there's no clutter in the logs. So for your template pics, you'd have something like:

`update template_pics SET image_file_name=NULL, image_content_type=NULL, image_file_size=NULL, image_updated_at=NULL;`

Make sure you have the style variants for your `missing.png` on development for this to be thorough.